# Appium simulator - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: appium, jscript

When I'm trying to use Appium 1.1.0.0 (Cygnus) - Android inspector - I'm receiving an error:

> Error: Object expected Code: 800A138F Source: Microsoft JScript
>   runtime error.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

I've just changed Android Home, so it can be related to it, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

After performing following steps the problem is solved:

1. Install nodejs
2. Double check if ANDROID_HOME is set correctly (I repasted the path)
3. Update Appium to the latest version